# Is there a way now to get requests in an Action in two different languages?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Is it possible to receive requests in two different languages in one Action, now that the Google Assistant is Bilingual: [image: Meet the multilingual Assistant]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible for on Action to be written to [work in multiple languages and locales](https://developers.google.com/actions/localization/). There's guidance in the documentation to extend a single Dialogflow agent as well. However, I don't believe the Action will be multilingual. It'll depend on what invocation phrase you use.

If you say "Talk to my test app", you'll get the English version.

If you say "parler avec mon application de test", you'll get the French version.

If your Action has a fulfillment, you'll be able to get the current locale by getting [`conv.user.locale`](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/classes/conversation.user.html#locale).

Comment: Nick, to clarify, are you saying that conv.user.locale can now have 2 different values on the same device? If yes, once invoked with one value, does that value have to stay the same during that conversation?

Comment: For a given conversation, you'll only have a constant locale. It will not switch in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. 
You select up multiple languages in console.Actions.google.com
You then add a second language to your project.
Under your project name you now have multiple language markers.
You have to set up intent verbal triggers for both the main language and also the secondary language in dialogflow.
It is in this way that the system recognises what language is being spoken and kicks off the appropriate intent. 
Note: If you use webhook functions they too will have to be updated to support multilingual functionality. I have implemented i18n as my framework.
There is a great tutorial at:
https://medium.com/voiceano/publishing-bilingual-actions-for-google-assistant-61c326d1b79?fbclid=IwAR1ysjBecJpZUP2bpUgXMZDkvpS6V4qvY75S0RdVw8q0PtZAjPMoTcty2vU